# C# File Naming Incremented Name 001++

Tags: c#, file, naming

I am using C# to create a small app. I need to name files in a recursive manner, incrementing the file names as they are created. I need a file name in the following format : "alt-001.tmp" "alt-002.tmp" and so on. I am always seeing the 00 removed before the incremented number, so for example, 001++ then returns 2 and not 002.

Thanks for your help and sorry if it sounds like a stupid question.

Comment: some sample code and a toy example would be nice, so people see what you tried. It will get you more response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this for format the number as a string:

```
fileName = string.format("alt-{0:000}.tmp", yourCounterVariable);
```

The string format command, replaces the "{0}" with the variable there. Then the values after the column are a mask on how that replacement should be formatted.

Answer (score 3):

You need to to a `ToString()` on the counter and use a format string.

```
var a = 0;
(a++).ToString("000").Dump();
(a++).ToString("000").Dump();
```

That will output to 3 digits for you.

Results:
    001
    002

Comment: Not everyone knows that `Dump()` is method from LinqPad

Comment: I used linqpad to test this so you can remove .Dump() and replace with Console.Writeline(...)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this noddy example?

```
int unique = 0;
string destPath = string.Format("alt-{0:000}.tmp", unique);
while (File.Exists(destPath))
{
     unique++;
     destPath = Path.Combine(easyPath, string.Concat(baseName, " ", unique.ToString("00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), file.Extension));
}
```